# Parse JSON response using SwiftyJSON iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I am trying to parse the following JSON response to get the **time** and **availability** for particular date using **SwiftyJSON**. 
I have successfully parsed to get the date from **timeSlots**.

However, I am unable to get the 'time' of particular date from the response.

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "doctorDetailsList": null,
  "doctorDetails": {
    "id": 219,
    "doctorName": "Doris Wunsch",
    "qualification": "MD",
    "consultationFee": 760,
    "experience": 0,
    "timeSlots": {
      "06/07/2016": [
        {
          "date": 1465432200000,
          "time": "6:00 AM",
          "availability": true
        },
        {
          "date": 1465452000000,
          "time": "11:30 AM",
          "availability": true
        }
      ],
      "06/08/2016": [
        {
          "date": 1465259400000,
          "time": "6:00 AM",
          "availability": true
        },
        {
          "date": 1465279200000,
          "time": "11:30 AM",
          "availability": true
        }
      ],
      "06/09/2016": [
        {
          "date": 1465365600000,
          "time": "11:30 AM",
          "availability": true
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "totalDoctors": 0,
  "message": null
}
```

This is what I did to get the **timeSlots** :

```
let todaysSlots = (self.doctorProfileDetail!["doctorDetails"]["timeSlots"].dictionary?.keys.sort()[0])!
```

in return, it's giving **"06/07/2016"**.

How do I get **time** and **availability**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the result:

```
let todaysDate = (self.doctorProfileDetail!["doctorDetails"]["timeSlots"]["06/07/2016"])[0]["time"]

let isAvailable = (self.doctorProfileDetail!["doctorDetails"]["timeSlots"]["06/07/2016"])[0]["availability"]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var Data :  NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

do {
    let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Swift", ofType: "json")!
    let url: NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
    let req: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    let data: NSData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(req, returningResponse: nil)
    let json: [NSObject : AnyObject] = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [NSObject : AnyObject]
     Data = json["doctorDetails"]?.valueForKey("timeSlots") as! NSMutableDictionary
       print(Data)
    let time : NSMutableDictionary = Data.valueForKey("06/07/2016")?.objectAtIndex(1) as! NSMutableDictionary
    let timestring = time.valueForKey("time") as! String
     print(timestring)
    let availability : NSMutableDictionary = Data.valueForKey("06/07/2016")?.objectAtIndex(1) as! NSMutableDictionary
    let numberbool = availability.valueForKey("availability") as! Bool
    print(numberbool)
```

you can use this code and get **time** and **availability** enjoy

Comment: Thank you @Dhiren for trying. However, I've got the solution and it's in answers below.